# What does this mean? 500 Error: schema is invalid: data.$ref should match format "uri-reference"

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

Used the lb4 generators to create models, repositories, and controllers.

When adding a new field to the model, my POST will start to fail with this error:
500 Error: schema is invalid: data.$ref should match format "uri-reference"

The error is too ambiguous, I have zero reference to what it's asking for.

The validation fails when it compares:

$schema = http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema

$ref = #/components/schemas/New User

*edit:* Apparently if you add a title option to the controller, it doesn't know  what to do with itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the title from *@requestBody*. Try the following:

```
@requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Population, {
            //title: "Add"
            exclude: ['id']
          })
        }
      }
```

Comment: Perhaps just a comma is omitted after the 'title' field?

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, same here. Apparently the getModelSchemaRef() "breaks" the model with the Title.
I commented that and  all run smoothly